# print(function) vs print(function()) in Python

Tags: python, function, printing

I've got following simple script, which gets text from some site:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def fetch_words():
    contentdownload = urlopen('https://wolnelektury.pl/media/book/txt/treny-tren-viii.txt')
    decluttered = []
    for line in contentdownload:
        decltr_line = line.decode('utf8').split("  ")
        for word in decltr_line:
            decluttered.append(word)
    contentdownload.close()
    return decluttered
```

**When adding:** `print(fetch_words)` at the end, **the program returns:** `<function fetch_words at 0x7fa440feb200>`, but on the other hand, when I replace it with: `print(fetch_words())` it returns the content of the website, that a function downloads.
I have following question: why it works like this, what's the difference: `function` with `()` or without...
**All help appreciated!**

Comment: The () call the function and "replace" it in the evaluation by its return value.

Comment: Since `fetch_words()` is a function, when you do `print(fetch_words)`, it just prints technical information and doesn't call the function.  When you do `print(fetch_words())`, it actually calls the function and runs it, and returns whatever you told it to.

Comment: I think print(fech_word) just prints the signature of the function because it does not include the parenthesis. But the second one returns the contents which include in the function.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `print(fetch_words)` you get the representation of the function as an object.

```
def fetch_words():
    pass

isinstance(fetch_words,object)
```

return `True`. Indeed, functions in Python are objects.

So when you type `print(fetch_words)` you actually get the result of `fetch_words.__str__()`, a special method which is called when you print object.

And when you type `print(fetch_words())` you get the result of the function (the value the function returns). Because, the `()` execute the function

So `fetch_words` is an object and `fetch_words()` execute the function and its value is the value the function returns.